# click function doesnt work with C# and DOM

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms, dom

So basically I want to press a button in a website and it doesn't work. The `HTML` line looks like this:

```
<div id="btn-login">
    <button type="submit">
       <span>SIGN IN THROUGH STEAM</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

And, the code line looks like this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btn-login").InvokeMember("click");
```

When I press the button nothing happens.
The website i'm using is http://csgowitch.com

Comment: The div is not the button. Move the `id="btn-login"` to the button tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the click is currently on the div around the button, not on the button itself. Since the button is the first child of the div, try this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btn-login").FirstChild.InvokeMember("click");
```